# unable to get value from global variable in php

Tags: php, wordpress, global-variables

This is the code I have in one of my php plugin file.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html','test_func');
function test_func() {
    global $woocommerce, $totalship;
    $cart_subtotal = (float)$woocommerce->cart->subtotal;
    if( $cart_subtotal < 1000 ) {
    $cart_subtotal01 = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
    $cart_subtotal11 = explode('</span>', $cart_subtotal01);
    $text_tax ='';
    if($cart_subtotal11[1]) {
        $text_tax = $cart_subtotal11[1];
    }
    $allcarttotal = $cart_subtotal+$totalship;  
    $value = '<strong><span class="amount">Rs.&nbsp;' . $allcarttotal . '</span>'.$text_tax.'</strong>';
    $citrus_total_val = $value;
    return $citrus_total_val;
        //return $value;
    }
    else {
    $docart_total = $cart_subtotal - $totalship;
    $citrus_total_val = $docart_total;
    return $citrus_total_val;
        //return $docart_total;
    }
}
global $citrus_total_val;
```

I am trying to pass the value of $citrus_total_val to another plugin for payment gateway.

This is the code:

```
  global $citrus_total_val; 

  //Setup URL and signatue etc.
  $currencycode = get_woocommerce_currency();       
  $merchantTxnId = $order_id;
  $orderAmount = $citrus_total_val;
```

But the value is not passed here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably need `global $citrus_total_val;` inside `test_func()`. Putting it outside doesn't do anything. Also, don't use globals, it's really hard to maintain code that uses globals.

Comment: What do you suggest I should use instead of globals?

Comment: Pass variables as arguments. Explicitly give functions everything they need. In the case of a return value, explicitly return the value. You're kinda doing both now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$citrus_total_val = '';
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html','test_func');
function test_func() {
    global $woocommerce, $totalship;
    global $citrus_total_val;
    $cart_subtotal = (float)$woocommerce->cart->subtotal;
    if( $cart_subtotal < 1000 ) {
    $cart_subtotal01 = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
    $cart_subtotal11 = explode('</span>', $cart_subtotal01);
    $text_tax ='';
    if($cart_subtotal11[1]) {
        $text_tax = $cart_subtotal11[1];
    }
    $allcarttotal = $cart_subtotal+$totalship;  
    $value = '<strong><span class="amount">Rs.&nbsp;' . $allcarttotal . '</span>'.$text_tax.'</strong>';
    $citrus_total_val = $value;
    return $citrus_total_val;
        //return $value;
    }
    else {
    $docart_total = $cart_subtotal - $totalship;
    $citrus_total_val = $docart_total;
    return $citrus_total_val;
        //return $docart_total;
    }
}
```

Comment: No! That doesn't work. But whatever value I put in $citrus_total_val outside the function test_func is passed to the other php.

Answer (score 0):

try putting it in the function, like you did with global $woocommerce, $totalship;

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html','test_func');
function test_func() {
    global $woocommerce, $totalship;
    global $citrus_total_val;
    $cart_subtotal = (float)$woocommerce->cart->subtotal;
    if( $cart_subtotal < 1000 ) {
    $cart_subtotal01 = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
    $cart_subtotal11 = explode('</span>', $cart_subtotal01);
    $text_tax ='';
    if($cart_subtotal11[1]) {
        $text_tax = $cart_subtotal11[1];
    }
    $allcarttotal = $cart_subtotal+$totalship;  
    $value = '<strong><span class="amount">Rs.&nbsp;' . $allcarttotal . '</span>'.$text_tax.'</strong>';
    $citrus_total_val = $value;
    return $citrus_total_val;
        //return $value;
    }
    else {
    $docart_total = $cart_subtotal - $totalship;
    $citrus_total_val = $docart_total;
    return $citrus_total_val;
        //return $docart_total;
    }
}
```

Comment: No! That doesn't work. But whatever value I put in $citrus_total_val outside the function test_func is passed to the other php.

Comment: It does make $citrus_total_val global....
You are manipulating the value of it here: $citrus_total_val = $value;
Please be more clear what you mean by your comment, I do not understand it.

Comment: If you want to debug your code, use $GLOBALS: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Comment: $citrus_total_val = '120';  If I do this outside of the function. The value 120 or whatever I put there is passed on to the other page.

Comment: No. What do you mean by 'other page'? GLOBALS do not survive a new script invocation. Use Session if you need that functionality.

Comment: other php page where I have got this code  :                                          global $citrus_total_val; 

  //Setup URL and signatue etc.
  $currencycode = get_woocommerce_currency();       
  $merchantTxnId = $order_id;
  $orderAmount = $citrus_total_val;